# Can you pay your domain with Amazon-Card

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am just curious and want to know whether i can pay with amazon cards or not. Otherwise i am looking for another option like google cloud hosting which should be much cheaper

Answer (score 1):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/accepted-payment-methods/, no.

All three major public cloud providers have different pricing for different services, but I don't think any of them are "much cheaper" than the other, unless you have some very specific workload.